Undefined array key, Opencart?
I´m trying to use a template for Opencart that I found on internet but after I installed the template and configured well Opencart I get this error if I try to publish any product.
Error code:

Warning: Undefined array key "video" in
/var/www/html/wooby/upload/extension/so_xtore/admin/controller/event/so_soconfig.php
on line 82Warning: Undefined array key "video" in
/var/www/html/wooby/upload/extension/so_xtore/admin/controller/event/so_soconfig.php
on line 82

And this is the line 82 in the file affected.
public function product_feature_list_after(string &$route, array &$data, mixed &$output): void {

        foreach($data['products'] as $item) {
            $yt2='<td class="text-left">'.$item['name']; 
            if($item['video'] and $item['tab_title']){ $yt2 .=' <span class="btn-primary">SO Feature</span>';

            $output = str_replace('<td class="text-start">'.$item['name'],$yt2,$output);


This code probably assumes a very tolerant PHP configuration. Use isset(), !empty() or array_key_exists() instead.

Duplicate: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP
